# anchor tag with k-button styling is still clickable when k-state-disabled is applied

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI, and I need to disable a button after it is clicked.

I'm applying the 'k-state-disabled' class inside the click event.

The button is visually disabled (it's faded out and looks disabled), but when I put the mouse cursor over it, I get the button's hover state, and if I click, I actually get a hit in my click event.

**Button Markup**

```
<a class="submitButton k-button" >Submit</a>
```

**Script**

```
$('.submitButton').live('click', function () {
    $('.submitButton').addClass("k-state-disabled");
    console.log("here");
});
```

[image: After clicking the button multiple times, I get this]

Is there something else I need to do in order to fully disabled this anchor?  I seem to remember disabled buttons working with just this in previous versions of Kendo, but now I'm not so sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always going to be disabled, even with the `k-state-disabled` class, that's just a class, not the removal of an actual event or disabled markup.

It looks like you're doing a link that's only meant to be clicked once, change your code to this:

```
$(document).one('click', '.submitButton', function () { // jquery .one will only fire the event once
    $(this).addClass("k-state-disabled");
    console.log("here");
});
```

Comment: I added that in my function and verified that I am having that property added, but further clicks on the button still result in the click event firing.

Comment: Actually, it's because your "button" isn't a button at all, it's a link. I'll re-do my code.

Comment: Awesome.  My bad on not clearly stating that it was a link with the styling of a button.  Thanks for the help and for being crazy quick!

Comment: but still clickable!